# Python dicts in a list, show highest score groupped by dictkey

Tags: python

I'm struggling to get the result from the following code:

```
list_result = [{'name':'John', 'score':5}, {'name':'John', 'score':6}, {'name':'James', 'score':7}, {'name':'James', 'score':8}]
```

My expected result is to group them by highest score (to show highest score per user), how do I do that?

Expected Result:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'score': 6}, {'name': 'James', 'score': 8}]
```

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Aren't scores 8 and 7 the highest?

Comment: @irahorecka, OP needs highest score per user.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, i need highest score per user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with an ordered dictionary, without pandas:

```
list_result = [{'name':'John', 'score':5}, {'name':'John', 'score':6}, {'name':'James', 'score':7}, {'name':'James', 'score':8}]

ord_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in sorted(list_result, key=lambda x: x["score"]):
    ord_dict[i["name"]] = i["score"]

print([{"name":k, "score":v} for k,v in ord_dict.items()])
```

The output is:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'score': 6}, {'name': 'James', 'score': 8}]
```

Comment: This is a good solution. You can also do the whole thing in one comprehension: `[max([entry for entry in list_result if entry['name'] == n], key=lambda x:x['score']) for n in set(entry['name'] for entry in list_result)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and its [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list_result)
>>> df.groupby('name').score.max().reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
[{'name': 'James', 'score': 8}, {'name': 'John', 'score': 6}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
import math

list_result = [
    {'name':'John', 'score': 5},
    {'name':'John', 'score': 6},
    {'name':'James', 'score': 7},
    {'name':'James', 'score': 8}
]

max_score_by_user = collections.defaultdict(lambda: -math.inf)
for result in list_result:
    name, score = result['name'], result['score']
    max_score_by_user[name] = max(max_score_by_user[name], score)

print(*max_score_by_user.items(), sep='\n')
```

Which prints:

```
('John', 6)
('James', 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
list_result = [{'name':'John', 'score':5}, {'name':'John', 'score':6}, {'name':'James', 'score':7}, {'name':'James', 'score':8}]
output_dict = {}

for result in list_result:
    if result["name"] in output_dict:
        if result["score"] > output_dict[result["name"]]:
            output_dict[result["name"]] = result["score"]
    else:
        output_dict[result["name"]] = result["score"]

output_list = []

for output_key, output_val in output_dict.items():
    output_list.append({"name": output_key, "score": output_val})

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'score': 6}, {'name': 'James', 'score': 8}]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':5874, 'z': 560}

key_max = max(my_dict.keys(), key=(lambda k: my_dict[k]))
key_min = min(my_dict.keys(), key=(lambda k: my_dict[k]))

print('Maximum Value: ',my_dict[key_max])
print('Minimum Value: ',my_dict[key_min])
```

Copy
Sample Output:

Maximum Value:  5874
Minimum Value:  500